# Python - What am I doing wrong with my generators?

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to yield a series of generators to another generator via helper functions. I guess I'm trying to mimic `flat_map()` like in RxPy. Is there a way to accomplish this? I am getting an output that is printing the generators, not the items yielded by the generators.

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}-{1}".format(self.id, self.name)

users = [
    User(0,"Hero"),
    User(1,"Dunn"),
    User(2,"Sue"),
    User(3,"Chi"),
    User(4,"Thor"),
    User(5,"Clive"),
    User(6,"Hicks"),
    User(7,"Devin"),
    User(8,"Kate"),
    User(9,"Klein"),
]

friendships = [
    (0,1),
    (0,2),
    (1,2),
    (1,3),
    (2,3),
    (3,4),
    (4,5),
    (5,6),
    (5,7),
    (6,8),
    (7,8),
    (8,9)
]

def user_for_id(user_id):
    for user in users:
        if user.id == user_id:
            yield user



def friends_of(user):
    for friendship in friendships:
        if friendship[0] == user.id or friendship[1] == user.id:
            for other_user_id in friendship:
                if other_user_id != user.id:
                    yield user_for_id(other_user_id)

for friend in friends_of(users[3]):
    print(friend)
```

OUTPUT:

```
<generator object user_for_id at 0x7f2d33ee48e0>
<generator object user_for_id at 0x7f2d33ee4990>
<generator object user_for_id at 0x7f2d33ee4938>
```

Comment: Why in the world did you make user_for_id() a generator?  It always yields exactly one item, you might as well have just ``return``ed it.  If you really want it to be a generator, you need to iterate over it and yield each of its values - or use `` yield from user_for_id(...`` in sufficiently recent Python versions (>=2.7, I think?)

Comment: Okay true, sorry I can' t break out of my functional mindset. I use reactive programming a lot. Let's assume it yields multiple items...

Comment: Ah, `yield from`! That's what I was looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your chaining generators together and only iterating over one of them. If you want to get the actually friends, you'll need to iterate over friend, even if it's a single value. Generators are NOT iterators. Because your `friends_of` function returns a generator expression, you either need to iterate over it or pass it to `next`.

```
>>> for friend in friends_of(users[3]):
...     for obj in friend:
...             print(obj.name)
...
Dunn
Sue
Thor
```

You can get around the second loop by passing the generator to `next()` and printing the resulting name property. I should note that this code is NOT the same as the code I previously mentioned, because this only looks at the first value returned by second generator expression.

```
>>> for friend in friends_of(users[3]):
...     print(next(friend).name)
...
Dunn
Sue
Thor
```

If you've having difficulty understanding generators I would highly suggest looking into the materials published on david beazley's website.

http://dabeaz.com/generators/index.html - Generator tricks for system programmers
http://dabeaz.com/generators-uk/index.html - Generator tricks for system programmers v2 
http://dabeaz.com/finalgenerator/index.html - Generators the final frontier

His videos and slides will give you a much better idea as to how generators work in python.

As somebody else explained, in Python 3 you can use "yield from":

```
def friends_of(user):
    for friendship in friendships:
        if friendship[0] == user.id or friendship[1] == user.id:
            for other_user_id in friendship:
                if other_user_id != user.id:
                    yield from user_for_id(other_user_id)

for friend in friends_of(users[3]):
    print(friend.name)
```

The deep nesting of the previous block of code is a bad sign though. It should be rewritten so that it is more readable.

Comment: "Generators are not iterators", okay that explains a lot of my misunderstanding. I would normally achieve what I'm looking for using [RxPy](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY), which supports unlimited composable iteration. I'm trying to learn the established Python approaches though, so thanks I'll check that out!

Comment: @ThomasN. In my opinion, David Beazley is THE authoritarian on Python generators. He's given numerous talk at python conferences across the world and is a well known member of the python community.